# What does the memory parameter -m for CF Push apply to in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Does -m parameter of CF Push apply to total memory available to container, memory available to droplet, total memory available to Droplet + RootFS + Buildpack files + environment variables or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the memory parameter -m for CF Push apply to in cloud foundry?

It sets the memory limit for the container where your application is executed. You can run whatever you want in the container, one process or multiple processes, in total their memory consumption needs to stay below the memory limit.

If you exceed your memory limit, the OOM killer will kick in and kill one of your processes, this will likely result in your application instance exiting and the platform will then restart the app. It usually results in an exit 137 being reported by `cf events`.

Please do not confuse memory limit with disk quota. Disk quota is specified with the `-k` flag. Disk quota does not include the rootfs, but does include the full droplet which in turn is all of your app bits plus anything installed by buildpacks.

Ex: 20M of app files + buildpack installs 200M = at least 220M of disk quota